# OpenCSV Parse CSV with header to List

Tags: java, parse-error, opencsv

I am trying to parse a simple csv file with some users using opencsv 3.3 and put it into a bean, but am getting a class not found exception when running the code.  The Person.class file I am using for the objects being read in is below.

```
public class Person {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String type;

    /*public Person () {}
    public Person (String firstname, String lastname, String email, String type) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.type = type;
    }*/

    //set all the variables for the person
    //set the first name
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    //set the last name
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastName (String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    //set the email address of the user
    public String setEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void getEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    //set the type for the user
    public String setType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void getType (String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", email=" + email + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }
}
```

The code for reading the csv is below.

```
String filename = "D:/Projects/deploy/resources/sample.csv";
try {          
    HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<Person> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<Person>();
    strategy.setType(Person.class);
    Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapping.put("firstname", "firstname");
    mapping.put("lastname", "lastname");
    mapping.put("email", "email");
    mapping.put("type", "type");
    strategy.setColumnMapping(mapping);
    System.out.println("past the mapping");

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
    System.out.println("past the reader");

    CsvToBean<Person> csvbean = new CsvToBean<Person>();
    System.out.println("past the csvtobean");

    List<Person> csvusers = csvbean.parse(strategy, reader);
    System.out.println(csvusers);


} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("there was an exception in the main program:" + e);
}
```

When I run this, it says that there is no class found for the header mapping.  Do you know if this is a problem with the Person.class or with the mapping?  Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone comes across this, the code above is working fine.  I did not have the apache commons lang3 in my classpath which was required for opencsv.  Once I added that, everything started working like it should.

Thanks
Nick